# Expose multiple Commands, each with different CommandParameters, from UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command, commandparameter

I have a `UserControl` that contains several buttons, and for each button I have a `Command` `DependencyProperty` defined. The UserControl XAML is (some elements removed for brevity):

```
<UserControl>
   <Grid>
      <Button Command="{Binding CloseCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" ToolTip="Delete">
      <Button Command="{Binding NavigateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" ToolTip="Launch">
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The DepencyProperties in the UserControl codebehind are:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CloseCommand", typeof (ICommand), typeof (Tile));

public ICommand CloseCommand
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CloseCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CloseCommandProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty NavigateCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("NavigateCommand", typeof (ICommand), typeof (Tile));

public ICommand NavigateCommand
{
    get { return (ICommand) GetValue(NavigateCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(NavigateCommandProperty, value); }
}
```

I'm using MVVM Light and I'm able to bind to these commands via `RelayCommands` on my ViewModel for the View that contains several instances of this `UserControl`. I'd like to be able to expose individual `CommandParameters` for each of the Commands on my UserControl. Is this possible?

In future I'd also like the entire `UserControl` (essentially the grid contained immediately within it) to expose commands for some other events (click, drag and data drop), again, each would expose its own `CommandParameters`.

I've not found much information about multiple `Command` and `CommandParameter` pairing, and so I'm wondering if I've taken the wrong approach. Would a `CustomControl` be more appropriate? Or would this be best solved using a `DataTemplate`? Exposing events like click and drag on a grid as commands also doesn't seem to have much coverage - is there a better container control that would suit my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `RelayCommand` to accept the `CommandParameter` like this -

```
closeCommand = new RelayCommand<bool>((flag) => Close(flag));

private void Test(bool flag)
{
    if(flag)
       CloseWindow();
}
```

i.e. by using the generic `RelayCommand<T>` implementation;

> The Execute method is passed to the RelayCommand’s constructor in form
>   of an Action (or Action if the command has a parameter, in which
>   case you must use the RelayCommand class).
>
> [Using RelayCommands in Silverlight 3 and WPF](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/26/using-relaycommands-in-silverlight-and-wpf.aspx)
>
> Ref. : - [Proposing a new RelayCommand snippet for MVVM Light V4](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2011/06/15/proposing-a-new-relaycommand-snippet-for-mvvm-light-v4.aspx)

and then pass the parameter using `CommandParameter` property of `Button`.

```
<Button Command="{Binding CloseCommand }" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding SomeCommandParameter}" ... />
```

Or

```
<Button Command="{Binding CloseCommand }" 
        CommandParameter="True" ... />
```

Comment: The CommandParameters for each button aren't available to me as they're wrapped in a UserControl. I'm exposing DependencyProperties on my UserControl which are bound to the buttons' commands, but this means my UserControl has multiple Commands and no paired CommandParameters.

Comment: I don't think you need that; just add the CommandParameter to the Button's you have; see updated code.